# Need to change the subdomain URL structure - D7

Tags: 7, uri, .htaccess, subsites

Need to change the subdomain URL structure from:

```
sub1.example.com
sub2.example.com
```

To:

```
www.example.com/sub1
www.example.com/sub2
```

Is there any module to do this in Drupal 7

If there is no other module in the text I need to rewrite the module for D7 version which is available in D6 in the below link. But before doing that I would like to confirm is there any modules ?

**Below text is taken from [the link](http://www.adherewebdesign.com/drupal-6-using-the-sub-domains-functionality-of-the-domains-module-while-using-sub-folder-type-url-structures/)**:

> Of course this could quite easily be achieved using a redirect /
>   RewriteRule in an htaccess file – but in this case we wanted to to
>   achieve the URL re-routing without actually using a redirect. In other
>   words, the URL in the browser’s address bar should always show URLs
>   like this

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will still need some mod_rewrite redirection rules (RewriteRule), but only after the fact; it can be used used to ensure users accessing subX.example.com get redirected appropriately to the new content URL instead of mod_rewrite being the solution to the problem (which, as you mentioned, is not what you wanted).

Have you tried using pathauto to set a URL pattern and then using views_bulk_operations to mass update node aliases? I recall VBO will overwrite any existing alias, but if it doesn't simply make a database backup for good measure and then drop your existing node path aliases from the database directly as they will be regenerated anyways using VBO.

If you need to create redirects from the old node aliases to the new ones (ignoring the hostname component), the redirect module will automatically create 301s.

Here is a quick guide on pathauto + VBO: http://drupal.org/node/1326928